# Winform Splash Screen - VB.NET - Timer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, splash-screen

I have a splash screen on the application and on that form. I have a timer.

```
Private Sub Splash_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   SplashTimer.Start()

   ' Set application title
   ' Set Version
 Me.Show()
        'Me.Refresh()
        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        'Login.ShowDialog()
        'Login.AllowTransparency = True
  End Sub
```

Interval on the timer is set to 5000.

```
  Private Sub SplashTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SplashTimer.Tick
        SplashTimer.Stop()
        Login.Show()
        Login.AllowTransparency = True
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
```

I set breakpoint here but it doesn't seem to hit this breakpoint. I uncommented Me.Refresh()

Splash screen is closing. Then Login is shown with a continue button. When you click continue
button

```
MainMenu.Show() 'this form should be shown as this is the main window of the application but it's not showing.
            Me.Close() 'closes login window
```

No window shows up and the application is hanging.
Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid the built-in SplashScreen form?

Comment: This is the current state of the application. I can suggest using the built in template.

Comment: @LarsTech - It is the built in template.

Comment: I have checked and it is a built in splash screen. Now I have removed the timer and let the thread sleep for 2 secs and it is closing the splash screen and the login form is showing up correctly on Continue button click - I am trying to show new form and close the current form (Login form) and it just doesn't display anything. If I only show the new form and not close the login form both are displayed correctly.

Comment: I just updated my answer, I just checked it to verify that it works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest using the built in Splash Screen that is provided by Visual Studio:

Go to the "Projects" menu and select "Add Windows Form" and select the Splash Screen template:

[image]

Then in the Project's Application settings, select that form to be the Splash screen:

[image]

Your start up form should be your login form, not the splash screen form.

**Update:**

Click on the "View Application Events" button on the last image from your My Project's Application screen and add this code to set the [MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234874%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) value:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Namespace My
  Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Protected Overrides Function OnInitialize(commandLineArgs As ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)) As Boolean
      Me.MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime = 5000
      Return MyBase.OnInitialize(commandLineArgs)
    End Function
  End Class
End Namespace
```

Your splash screen will remain on the screen for 5000 milliseconds, or 5 seconds.

Comment: @kalls I've updated the answer with an example to add a delay for the splash screen.  No timer is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a Module to your program with a `Public Sub Main` Method. Set your project Startup options to Sub Main. You can then do something like:

```
Module Module1
    Dim frmSplash As SplashScreen1
    Dim frmLogin As Login
    Dim frmMain As MainMenu
    Dim splashTimer As Timer

    Public Sub Main()
        splashTimer = New Timer()
        AddHandler splashTimer.Tick, AddressOf TimerTick
        splashTimer.Interval = 5000
        splashTimer.Start()
        frmSplash = New SplashScreen1
        frmSplash.ShowDialog()

        frmLogin = New Login
        Dim result As DialogResult = frmLogin.ShowDialog
        If result <> DialogResult.OK Then
            End
        End If

        frmMain = New MainMenu
        frmMain.ShowDialog()

    End Sub
    Private Sub TimerTick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        splashTimer.Stop()
        frmSplash.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Project Settings:

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried this Mr. Hall. The previous approach worked for me. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that timer events aren't fired until the Load event/method is completed.
I put a thread.sleep in the activated event/method and it gives me the desired result.
So I'm trying to show a splash screen with a couple different background images and this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I Found A sample Solution (My SplashScreen Named  "**Loading**" and My Start Form Named "**login**")

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Timer1.Interval = 5000 Then
        Me.Hide()
        Login.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```