# What causes the SplashScreen to Close and can I influence this

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, splash-screen

Simple question but I can't seem to find the answer - can someone tell me which event causes the splash screen to be closed.

I thought it would be either the startupform.Activated or some application level event but I can't find it.

The reason for the question is that I want to control when the splash screen is closed myself - can I do this?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to set the [`MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.minimumsplashscreendisplaytime.aspx)?

Comment: It is the Load event of your MainForm.  Possibly extended past that by MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime, 2 seconds by default.

Comment: That works to make it show for longer, but I don't know exactly how long the startup will take so can I close it before the `MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime` is up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cody Gray remarked, the `MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime` property controls this, which was part of an answer I recently posted here: [Winform Splash Screen - VB.NET - Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993905/719186)

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Namespace My
  Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Protected Overrides Function OnInitialize(commandLineArgs As ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)) As Boolean
      Me.MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime = 5000
      Return MyBase.OnInitialize(commandLineArgs)
    End Function
  End Class
End Namespace
```

This code comes from clicking on the "View Application Events" button in "My Project", "Application" tab.

Comment: But I don't know how long the startup will take, so can I control when the form is closed if it is less than the Minimum?

Comment: @Matt Do all of your startup stuff in the Load event of the Main form.  The splash form won't close until the main form becomes activated, which happens after the load event completes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.minimumsplashscreendisplaytime.aspx) on this issue